# Is it possible to selectively read from AWS SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, amazon-sqs

I have a use-case. I want to read from SQS always, except when another event happens.

For instance, I have football news into SQS as messages. I want to retrieve them always, except for times when live matches are happening.

Is there any possibility to read unless there is another event does the job?

I scrolled the docs and Stack Overflow, but I don't see a solution.

**COMMENT:** I have a small and week service, and I cannot because of technical limitations increase it (memory/CPU, etc.), but I still want 2 "conflicting" flows to be in the service. They are both supposed to communicate to the same API, and I don't want them to send conflicting requests.

Is there a way to do it, or will I have to write a custom communicator with SQS?

Comment: It sounds like your question isn't really about AWS at all. You just want to pause one service/thread/whatever on your server when another one is running? You just need some sort of flag or lock that one process can set, and the other process can check that before polling SQS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select which messages you want to read from SQS and which you'd rather not - there is no filtering in SQS.

If you have messages that need to be processed at all times and others that need to be processed only sometimes or in batches, you should put them in separate queues and read from the seperately.

You don't say anything about the infrastructure that reads from the queue, but if it's a process on EC2, you could just stop it while live matches are happening and restart it later. SQS is built for asynchronous messaging and will store the messages for up to 14 days (depending on your configuration) until a consumer is available to read them.